# C# and PHP ECDH not matching

Tags: c#, php, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to generate a shared secret between a web server running PHP and a C# desktop application. I'm aware of the BouncyCastle library, but I'd prefer not having to use it since it's pretty huge.

I'm using [phpecc](https://github.com/phpecc/phpecc) and [ECDiffieHellmanCng](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.110).aspx) and trying to generate a shared secret between the two parties but I'm having issues with exporting/importing in C#.

It seems phpecc requires der/pem format in order to import a key, and ECDiffieHellmanCng doesn't seem to have any easy way to export in a compatible format.

Would I need to write my own pem/der encoder and decoder in order to do this or is there some alternative easier way?

Currently I'm doing the following in C#:

```
using (var ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
        {
            ecdh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP384;
            ecdh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;

            var encoded = EncodePem(ecdh.PublicKey.ToByteArray()); 
            //... do something with encoded
        }

private static string EncodePem(byte[] data)
    {
        var pemDat = new StringBuilder();
        var chunk = new char[64];

        pemDat.AppendLine("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");

        var encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < encodedData.Length; i += chunk.Length)
        {
            var index = 0;
            while (index != chunk.Length && i + index < encodedData.Length)
            {
                chunk[index] = encodedData[i + index];
                index++;
            }
            pemDat.AppendLine(new string(chunk));
        }

        pemDat.AppendLine("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
        return pemDat.ToString();
    }
```

Obviously the above is only doing the pem encoding, so on the php side it returns an error when it's trying to parse it:

> Type: Runtime
>
> Exception Message: Invalid data.
>
> File: /.../vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Serializer/PublicKey/Der/Parser.php
>
> Line: 49

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Core 1.0 and [.NET Framework 4.7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/) have the [ECParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) struct to import/export keys.  The `ToByteArray()` method you called is producing a [CNG EccPublicBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375520(v=vs.85).aspx) which has very little to do with the SEC-1 ECParameters format.

I'm going to assume that you wanted to use secp384r1/NIST P-384, even though you specified that as a hash algorithm.  If you want some other curve, you'll need to do some translations.

The (.NET) ECParameters struct will only help you get started.  Turning that into a file requires translating it into a PEM-encoded DER-encoded ASN.1-based structure. (But if you're sticking with NIST P-256/384/521, you can do it with the byte[] you currently have)

In [SEC 1 v2.0](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) we get the following structures:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier {{ECPKAlgorithms}} (WITH COMPONENTS {algorithm, parameters}),
  subjectPublicKey BIT STRING
}

ECPKAlgorithms ALGORITHM ::= {
  ecPublicKeyType |
  ecPublicKeyTypeRestricted |
  ecPublicKeyTypeSupplemented |
  {OID ecdh PARMS ECDomainParameters {{SECGCurveNames}}} |
  {OID ecmqv PARMS ECDomainParameters {{SECGCurveNames}}},
  ...
}

ecPublicKeyType ALGORITHM ::= {
  OID id-ecPublicKey PARMS ECDomainParameters {{SECGCurveNames}}
}

ECDomainParameters{ECDOMAIN:IOSet} ::= CHOICE {
  specified SpecifiedECDomain,
  named ECDOMAIN.&id({IOSet}),
  implicitCA NULL
}

An elliptic curve point itself is represented by the following type
  ECPoint ::= OCTET STRING
whose value is the octet string obtained from the conversion routines given in Section 2.3.3.
```

Distilling this down to the relevant parts, you need to write

```
SEQUENCE (SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
  SEQUENCE (AlgorithmIdentifier)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER id-ecPublicKey
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER secp384r1 (or whatever named curve you're using)
  BIT STRING
    public key encoded as ECPoint
```

The AlgorithmIdentifier contains data that's fixed given you don't change the curve:

```
SEQUENCE (AlgorithmIdentifier)
30 xx [yy [zz]]
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER id-ecPublicKey (1.2.840.10045.2.1)
   06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER secp384r1 (1.3.132.0.34)
   06 05 2B 81 04 00 22
```

and we can now count how many bytes were in the payload: 16 (0x10), so we fill in the length:

```
30 10 06 07  2A 86 48 CE   3D 02 01 06  05 2B 81 04
00 22
```

The public key encoding that everyone understands is "uncompressed point", which is

```
04 th eb yt es of x. th eb yt es of y.
```

Turns out, that has a fixed size for a given curve, too, so unlike most things that are DER encoded, you can do this in one pass :).  For secp384r1 the x and y coordinate are each 384 bit values, or (384 + 7)/8 == 48 bytes, so the ECPoint is 48 + 48 + 1 == 97 (0x61) bytes. Then it needs to be wrapped in a BIT STRING, which adds one payload byte and the length and tag. So, we get:

```
private static byte[] s_secp384r1PublicPrefix = {
    // SEQUENCE (SubjectPublicKeyInfo, 0x76 bytes)
    0x30, 0x76,
    // SEQUENCE (AlgorithmIdentifier, 0x10 bytes)
    0x30, 0x10,
    // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (id-ecPublicKey)
    0x06, 0x07, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x02, 0x01,
    // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (secp384r1)
    0x06, 0x05, 0x2B, 0x81, 0x04, 0x00, 0x22,
    // BIT STRING, 0x61 content bytes, 0 unused bits.
    0x03, 0x62, 0x00,
    // Uncompressed EC point
    0x04,
}

...

using (ECDiffieHellman ecdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create())
{
    ecdh.KeySize = 384;

    byte[] prefix = s_secp384r1PublicPrefix;
    byte[] derPublicKey = new byte[120];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(prefix, 0, derPublicKey, 0, prefix.Length);

    byte[] cngBlob = ecdh.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
    Debug.Assert(cngBlob.Length == 104);

    Buffer.BlockCopy(cngBlob, 8, derPublicKey, prefix.Length, cngBlob.Length - 8);

    // Now move it to PEM
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");
    builder.AppendLine(
        Convert.ToBase64String(derPublicKey, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
    builder.AppendLine("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
}
```

Running the output I got from that into OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl ec -pubin -text -noout
read EC key
(paste)
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEwpbxYmcsNvr14D8k+0VQCkSY4WCV/3V10AiIq7sFdmUX
9+0DMuuLDmcKjL1ZFEFk0yHCPpY+pdkYtzPwE+dsApCPT3Ljk0AxHQBTSo4yjwsElMoA4Mtp8Qdo
LZD1Nx6v
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
Private-Key: (384 bit)
pub:
    04:c2:96:f1:62:67:2c:36:fa:f5:e0:3f:24:fb:45:
    50:0a:44:98:e1:60:95:ff:75:75:d0:08:88:ab:bb:
    05:76:65:17:f7:ed:03:32:eb:8b:0e:67:0a:8c:bd:
    59:14:41:64:d3:21:c2:3e:96:3e:a5:d9:18:b7:33:
    f0:13:e7:6c:02:90:8f:4f:72:e3:93:40:31:1d:00:
    53:4a:8e:32:8f:0b:04:94:ca:00:e0:cb:69:f1:07:
    68:2d:90:f5:37:1e:af
ASN1 OID: secp384r1
NIST CURVE: P-384
```