# C# Get CngKey object from public key in text file

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I have got a file in which there are several public keys for ECDSA SHA256. The file looks like:

```
KEY_ID: 1
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjp
WVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 2
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+Y5mYZL/EEY9zGji+hrgGkeoyccK
D0/oBoSDALHc9+LXHKsxXiEV7/h6d6+fKRDb6Wtx5cMzXT9HyY+TjPeuTg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 3
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEkvgJ6sc2MM0AAFUJbVOD/i34YJJ8
ineqTN+DMjpI5q7fQNPEv9y2z/ecPl8qPus8flS4iLOOxdwGoF1mU9lwfA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How can I can get CngKey object (or list of CngKey) for one (or all) of these keys?

I have tried something like

```
string plainTextKey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjpWVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==";
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(plainTextKey);
CngKey ret = CngKey.Import(publicKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

but Import method throws System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException for invalid parameter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`EccPublicBlob` maps to [BCRYPT_ECCPUBLIC_BLOB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375472(v=vs.85).aspx) format type, not X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo.

If all of your keys are on secp256r1/NIST P-256 then there's a pretty straightforward hacky approach.

You may have noticed that all of your keys start with `MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE`.  We'll see why shortly.

Convert

```
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjp
WVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==
```

to bytes (or, here, hex):

```
30 59 30 13 06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01 06 08 2A 
86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07 03 42 00 04 6A AE 9D 8F 2C 
E4 A4 77 57 EE 4B 7C 0E C4 AD E8 8B 92 A1 78 E9 
59 59 4B 7E 76 4F A0 B6 86 29 CF F6 05 27 D8 42 
E1 48 3B 68 5F 82 E7 90 20 D2 4D DD 97 6E 8D 85 
DF 50 9E D6 86 8F 97 91 C2 6A 1D
```

This is a DER encoded [X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) blob.

Using our DER-fu we see

```
// SubjectPublicKeyInfo
30 59  // SEQUENCE, 0x59 == 89 bytes of payload
   // AlgorithmIdentifier
   30 13  // SEQUENCE, 0x13 == 19 bytes of payload
      // AlgorithmIdentifier.algorithm
      06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01  // OBJECT ID 1.2.840.10045.2.1 (id-ecPublicKey)
      // AlgorithmIdentifier.parameters
      06 08 2A 86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07 // OBJECT ID 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 (secp256r1)
   // SubjectPublicKeyInfo.publicKey
   03 42 00  // BIT STRING, 0x42 == 66 (65) payload bytes, 0 unused bits
      // "the public key"
      04
      92F809EAC73630CD000055096D5383FE2DF860927C8A77AA4CDF83323A48E6AE
      DF40D3C4BFDCB6CFF79C3E5F2A3EEB3C7E54B888B38EC5DC06A05D6653D9707C
```

Since the algorithm identifier is `id-ecPublicKey` the parameters is an OID identifying the curve (in this case, secp256r1 / NIST P-256).  And "the public key" is of a format from [SEC 1 v2.0](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) (2.3.4 Octet-String-to-Elliptic-Curve-Point Conversion).

The most common encoding is type `04`, uncompressed key. (0x04 followed by Qx padded to the necessary length followed by Qy padded to the necessary length).

So, for all points encoded with type 04 on secp256r1 the byte pattern starts with

```
30 59 30 13 06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01 06 08 2A 
86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07 03 42 00 04
```

which happens to align to a common base64 prefix of `MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE`.

What [CNG wants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375520(v=vs.85).aspx) is [32-bit identifier][32-bit little-endian length][padded Qx][padded Qy].

So the super-duper hacky version is:

```
private static readonly byte[] s_secp256r1Prefix =
    Convert.FromBase64String("MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE");

// For ECDH instead of ECDSA, change 0x53 to 0x4B.
private static readonly byte[] s_cngBlobPrefix = { 0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x31, 0x20, 0, 0, 0 };

private static CngKey ImportECDsa256PublicKey(string base64)
{
    byte[] subjectPublicKeyInfo = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    if (subjectPublicKeyInfo.Length != 91)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    byte[] prefix = s_secp256r1Prefix;

    if (!subjectPublicKeyInfo.Take(prefix.Length).SequenceEqual(prefix))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    byte[] cngBlob = new byte[s_cngBlobPrefix.Length + 64];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(s_cngBlobPrefix, 0, cngBlob, 0, s_cngBlobPrefix.Length);

    Buffer.BlockCopy(
        subjectPublicKeyInfo,
        s_secp256r1Prefix.Length,
        cngBlob,
        s_cngBlobPrefix.Length,
        64);

    return CngKey.Import(cngBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
}
```

To support other curves you need to change the first 4 bytes of the CNG blob to the correct "Magic" value, and change the 5th byte to be the correct length.  And, of course, different SubjectPublicKeyInfo prefixes, and 64 won't be the public key coordinate length (64 == 256 / 8 * 2).  But all of that is left as an exercise to the reader.

See [C# and PHP ECDH not matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871026/c-sharp-and-php-ecdh-not-matching/43897367#43897367) for the reverse.

Comment: What a comprehensive answer. Clapping my hands.

Comment: @bartonjs, do you happen to have example code for secp384r1? (NIST CURVE P-384)

Comment: Thank you very much.  After spending a week finally got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been parsing files like this for 40 years.  Code like this has long history

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication62
{
    enum State
    {
        FIND_KEY,
        GET_STATUS,
        GET_KEY_STRINGS
    }
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Key(FILENAME);

        }

    }
    public class Key
    {
        public static List<Key> keys = new List<Key>();

        public int id { get; set; }
        public Boolean status { get; set; }
        List<string> keysStrs = new List<string>();

        public Key() { }
        public Key(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string inputLine = "";

            State state = State.FIND_KEY;
            Key newKey = null;
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if(inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_KEY :
                            if(inputLine.StartsWith("KEY_ID:"))
                            {
                                newKey = new Key();
                                keys.Add(newKey);
                                int id = int.Parse(inputLine.Substring(inputLine.LastIndexOf(" ")));
                                newKey.id = id;
                                state = State.GET_STATUS;
                            }
                            break;

                        case State.GET_STATUS:
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("STATUS:"))
                            {
                                string status = inputLine.Substring(inputLine.LastIndexOf(" ")).Trim();
                                newKey.status = status == "VALID" ? true : false;
                                state = State.GET_KEY_STRINGS;
                            }                            
                            break;

                        case State.GET_KEY_STRINGS:
                            if (!inputLine.StartsWith("-"))
                            {
                                newKey.keysStrs.Add(inputLine.Trim());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (inputLine.Contains("END PUBLIC KEY"))
                                {
                                    state = State.FIND_KEY;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to parse the file with keys, but I cannot get CngKey object from parsed plaintext public key.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct settings including SHA256?  I've seen similar errors before with decrypt/encrpt.  Last time I had issues there were 5 different parameter setting so I wrote a 5 nested for loop and tried all options until I found the correct option.  Put some exception handlers in the loops so code continue when exception occur.   I found correct combination of properties.  The documentation is sometimes very vague.