# How to convert ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey instance to DER file in .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, elliptic-curve, der

I have following code:

```
ECDiffieHellman ecdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey ecdhPublic = ecdh.PublicKey;
```

How can I export the ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey instance (ecdhPublic) into DER encoded file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502331/c-sharp-get-cngkey-object-from-public-key-in-text-file/44527439#44527439, but in reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BouncyCastle (http://www.bouncycastle.org/) you can export your ECDH public key to a DER encoded ANS.1 Object

```
X9ECParameters ecP = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
ECDomainParameters ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, ecP.G, ecP.N, ecP.H, ecP.GetSeed());
ECKeyPairGenerator g = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
g.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, new SecureRandom()));

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair server = g.GenerateKeyPair();
ECPublicKeyParameters serverPub = (ECPublicKeyParameters)server.Public;
var result = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(serverPub).GetDerEncoded();
```

Comment: How can I get ECPublicKeyParameters directly given that I have X and Y ordinates of the point for the P-256 curve?

Comment: Not entirely sure, haven't come to that usecase yet. Probably will look somewhere along the lines of:                 

`BigInteger x = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger y = new BigInteger("0");
ECPoint example = ecP.Curve.CreatePoint(x, y); //needs to be a bouncy castle biginteger x, y

ECDomainParameters ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, example, ecP.N, ecP.H, ecP.GetSeed());`

Comment: Tried following and it worked. string curveName = "P-256";
X9ECParameters ecP = NistNamedCurves.GetByName(curveName);
FpCurve c = (FpCurve)ecP.Curve;
byte[] pointBytes =
    Utility.HexToBytes(
        "0418a3d65a2f886e0ba479e75912b0a04b35724f99369d36a87babbcd780d40d73208c2a105a91d7a98b38169bb69fcdadb98c0a13cdbdf8752e2ea20468101af8");
var q = c.DecodePoint(pointBytes);
var keyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters("ECDH", q, SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP256r1);
var result = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyParameters).GetDerEncoded();