# Microsoft CNG | How to import PEM encoded ECDSA private key into MS Key Storage Provider

Tags: openssl, cryptography, pem, ecdsa, cng

I know the MS CNG private have this format -

`BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB
BYTE X[cbKey] // Big-endian.
BYTE Y[cbKey] // Big-endian.
BYTE d[cbKey] // Big-endian.`

Thus tried to import below key bytes -

```
byte[] ec256PrivKB =
{
//Magic + CBLength
0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x31, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
//X
0xA7, 0xFB, 0xCD, 0x4D, 0x7E, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x22, 0xBD, 0x74, 0xFA, 0x1F, 0xD7, 0x10, 0xDB, 0x8C, 0xF8, 0x29, 0xC1, 0xEC, 0x5E, 0x15, 0x1E, 0xE2, 0x84, 0x56, 0x3E, 0x54, 0x6E, 0x1D, 0x5C, 0xF6, 
//Y
0x6B, 0x42, 0x21, 0xD1, 0x92, 0xEB, 0x69, 0x66, 0x56, 0xD6, 0xEC, 0x4D, 0x21, 0xB7, 0xDB, 0x3C, 0x94, 0x56, 0x8D, 0x87, 0xEB, 0x1C, 0x11, 0x0F, 0x03, 0x80, 0xF6, 0x10, 0x70, 0x73, 0x7D, 0x1D, 
//D
0x5E, 0xF0, 0x2A, 0x1B, 0x34, 0xE9, 0x2B, 0x96, 0xA4, 0xAE, 0x05, 0x1D, 0x33, 0x53, 0x36, 0x39, 0x7B, 0x1F, 0xF5, 0x24, 0xA4, 0xD6, 0xBD, 0x12, 0x07, 0x3F, 0x43, 0x30, 0x70, 0x32, 0x4E, 0x5D
};
```

Now on calling

```
ECDsaCng eCDsa = new ECDsaCng( CngKey.Import(ec256PrivKB, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob,
                    CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider));
```

It gives `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The requested operation is not supported.`
I don't understand why it is giving this exception ?

Also how to import base64 encoded ecdsa private key into MS key storage provider i.e suppose i have below ec private key -

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEICWeuFHssg5i2vJlyMHPUb+DJnylxfbkR8KJPXfYw5ikoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAE7A4wVMLQ+orOZYcFv6mLNBbAWfffPwTTw4iroyQDcytYWT+frzl3
RiFXqC1niHgduYtGBZIbwq/48ooyL9HbkA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now how do i import this into CNG provider ?

**Edit** - Also is there any way to reciprocate this process i.e 
I know how to convert from `OpenSSL(PEM FORMAT)` to `MS Format(RAW format)`
but how to do the reverse meaning
how to convert `MS` Format ECDSA Key to `OpenSSL` EC Key in PEM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your key blob starts with BCRYPT_ECDSA_**PUBLIC**_P256_MAGIC, but you want BCRYPT_ECDSA_**PRIVATE**_P256_MAGIC (change the 0x31 to 0x32).

From that we could assume that you know how to do the conversion, but since the title asks how to do it more generally I'll continue.  [C# Get CngKey object from public key in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44502331/6535399) has a straightforward (if hacky) answer to public keys.  Private keys are different, but mostly straightforward.

If we take the PEM key from the question we can remove the "PEM armor" to get a base-64 blob.  Turning that base-64 blob into hexadecimal we get

```
30 77 02 01 01 04 20 25 9E B8 51 EC B2 0E 62 DA 
F2 65 C8 C1 CF 51 BF 83 26 7C A5 C5 F6 E4 47 C2 
89 3D 77 D8 C3 98 A4 A0 0A 06 08 2A 86 48 CE 3D 
03 01 07 A1 44 03 42 00 04 EC 0E 30 54 C2 D0 FA 
8A CE 65 87 05 BF A9 8B 34 16 C0 59 F7 DF 3F 04 
D3 C3 88 AB A3 24 03 73 2B 58 59 3F 9F AF 39 77 
46 21 57 A8 2D 67 88 78 1D B9 8B 46 05 92 1B C2 
AF F8 F2 8A 32 2F D1 DB 90
```

If we then open https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf section C.4 we see

```
ECPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
  version INTEGER { ecPrivkeyVer1(1) } (ecPrivkeyVer1),
  privateKey OCTET STRING,
  parameters [0] ECDomainParameters {{ SECGCurveNames }} OPTIONAL,
  publicKey [1] BIT STRING OPTIONAL
}
```

Via the ASN.1 ([ITU-T X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.680-200811-S!!PDF-E&type=items)) and BER/DER ([ITU-T X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-200811-S!!PDF-E&type=items)) specifications we can blend that hex dump and that structure:

```
// (constructed) SEQUENCE, 119 content bytes
30 77
   // INTEGER, 1 content byte, value 0x01.
   02 01 01
   // OCTET STRING (byte[]), 32 bytes, value 25 9E ... 98 A4
   04 20
      25 9E B8 51 EC B2 0E 62 DA F2 65 C8 C1 CF 51 BF 
      83 26 7C A5 C5 F6 E4 47 C2 89 3D 77 D8 C3 98 A4
   // (constructed) CONTEXT-SPECIFIC 0, 10 content bytes
   A0 0A
      // OBJECT IDENTIFIER, 8 content bytes, 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7
      06 08 2A 86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07
   // (constructed) CONTEXT-SPECIFIC 1, 68 content bytes
   A1 44
      // BIT STRING, 66 content bytes, 0 unused bits, value 04 EC .. DB 90
      03 42
         00
         04 EC 0E 30 54 C2 D0 FA 8A CE 65 87 05 BF A9 8B 
         34 16 C0 59 F7 DF 3F 04 D3 C3 88 AB A3 24 03 73 
         2B 58 59 3F 9F AF 39 77 46 21 57 A8 2D 67 88 78 
         1D B9 8B 46 05 92 1B C2 AF F8 F2 8A 32 2F D1 DB 
         90
```

Doing a [search for 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.10045.3.1.7) indicates that it is (unsurprisingly) the secp256r1 / NIST P-256 elliptic curve.

The contents of the BIT STRING start with `04`, which indicates that it is an uncompressed EC point, the first half of what remains is the X coordinate, and the second half is the Y coordinate.  Nicely, this lines up with the width of the OCTET STRING for the private key, meaning the structure is valid.

You'll note that the ASN.1 structure said that the curve identifier and the public key were technically both optional.  In practice they are written down, which is good, since we're going to count on it.

## Converting an EC Private Key blob to the CNG blob

```
// structure opening up to the private key (D) value.
private static readonly byte[] s_secp256R1Prefix =
    { 0x30, 0x77, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04, 0x20 };

// After D through the 0x04 identifying the public key is uncompressed
private static readonly byte[] s_secp256R1Infix =
{
    0xA0, 0x0A, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE,
    0x3D, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0xA1, 0x44, 0x03, 0x42,
    0x00, 0x04
};

private static readonly byte[] s_secp256R1PrivateCngPrefix =
    { 0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x32, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

private static CngKey DecodeP256ECPrivateKeyBase64(string base64)
{
    byte[] derBlob = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    if (derBlob.Length == 121 &&
        derBlob.Take(s_secp256R1Prefix.Length).SequenceEqual(s_secp256R1Prefix) &&
        derBlob.Skip(0x20 + s_secp256R1Prefix.Length).Take(s_secp256R1Infix.Length).
            SequenceEqual(s_secp256R1Infix))
    {
        byte[] cngBlob = new byte[2 * sizeof(uint) + 3 * 0x20];
        int offset = 0;

        // Header (BCRYPT_ECDSA_PRIVATE_P256_MAGIC and 0x00000020)
        Buffer.BlockCopy(
            s_secp256R1PrivateCngPrefix,
            0,
            cngBlob,
            offset,
            s_secp256R1PrivateCngPrefix.Length);

        offset += s_secp256R1PrivateCngPrefix.Length;

        // X and Y
        Buffer.BlockCopy(
            derBlob,
            s_secp256R1Prefix.Length + 0x20 + s_secp256R1Infix.Length,
            cngBlob,
            offset,
            2 * 0x20);

        offset += 2 * 0x20;

        Buffer.BlockCopy(
            derBlob,
            s_secp256R1Prefix.Length,
            cngBlob,
            offset,
            0x20);

        offset += 0x20;
        Debug.Assert(offset == cngBlob.Length);

        return CngKey.Import(cngBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to decode the pem to the key... but I have p-521 curve instead of p-256..I am trying to use above example but problem is that first two bytes are 0x30 and 0x81 which might be fine but after that I get 0xDC which is not a know type.. can you please see my question here and give me a hint thanks
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/95353/openssl-ec-private-key-content-structure-details

Comment: @bartonjs  Your explanation is very in-depth, but does every developer who want to import a key & certificate really need to jump through all these holes and know all these structures?  Does the Windows API not offer a way to hide all of this from the developer?

Comment: @bartonjs  
Basically, for me, the key and certificate should just be a black box.  I get them as a text blob and I need to pass them to a keystore/certstore.  So, I'd prefer not having to know any ASN.1 or bit-banging details and just pass a PEM text to a function that then provides a CNG key handle back.  Without needing to know myself whether the key is RSA or EC or whatever.  Is that somehow possible?

Comment: @Mr.K There wasn’t when I wrote the answer, no. With .NET 5 it’s a lot easier using X509Certofocate2.CreateFromPem. With CNG directly I don’t think it’s any easier than this.