# How to compute the ECDSA signature using a P-256 key in a PEM file using C#.NET?

Tags: .net, cryptography, digital-signature, ecdsa, cng

I am new to cryptography and in over my head trying to sort it out on Windows, using C#.NET

I generated an elliptic curve P-256 (a.k.a. secp256r1 and prime256v1) key using the following command:

```
openssl ecparam –name prime256v1 -genkey –noout –out private.key
```

I generated a certificate signing request using the following command:

```
openssl req –new –key private.key –out certreq.csr –sha256
```

Another team sent me a base-64 encoded certificate in response. So far so good.

I have now received some "test" data that I need to compute the ECDSA signature of, using the private-key. The private key looks something like:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
FunnyHow?LIKEACLOWN?DOIAMUSEYOU?DOIMAKEYOULAUGH?==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have been struggling with code similar to the following so far:

```
byte[] cngBlob; // This was calculated based on another StackOverFlow post
byte[] testData       = "JoePesciWasGreatInGoodfellas";
CngKey cngKey         = CngKey.Import(cngBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
ECDsaCng eCDsaCng     = new ECDsaCng(cngKey);
byte[] signatureECDSA = eCDsaCng.SignData(testData);
```

I tried calculating `byte[] cngBlob` using the private-key file, based on [Microsoft CNG | How to import PEM encoded ECDSA private key into MS Key Storage Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080937/microsoft-cng-how-to-import-pem-encoded-ecdsa-private-key-into-ms-key-storage)
but however am not getting the correct answer in `byte[] signatureECDSA`.

How do I read in the private key from the file and then use it to compute the ECDSA signature of the test data?

I have started to delve into the fascinating world of cryptography but it will take me some time to get familiar with it. Am I on the right track here? Any tips in the meantime to help me with this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: The link in your question shows you how to do it. If it isn't working then you are obligated to provide the code that isn't working and the details of the problem.

Comment: It turns out that the code above was right. I had actually calculated a hash of the test data using
byte[] HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byte[] buffer)
and it was this hash that I was attempting to sign. I did not realize that calculating the hash would make all the difference.

The correct call I had to use turns out to be 
byte[] signatureECDSA = eCDsaCng.SignData(testData);

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the code above was the correct approach, but for a mistake I made. I had actually calculated a hash of the test data using the method

```
byte[] HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byte[] buffer)
```

and it was this hashed value of the test data that I was trying to sign.  My test data above should probably have looked like

```
     byte[] testData = null;
     using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
     {
        testData = sha256.ComputeHash("JoePesciWasGreatInGoodfellas");
     }
```

I did not realize that calculating the hash would make all the difference.

The correct call I had to use to sign the hashed test data turns out to be

```
byte[] signatureECDSA = eCDsaCng.SignHash(testData);
```

Here is what the final corrected code would look like:

```
byte[] cngBlob; // This was calculated based on another StackOverFlow post
byte[] testData = null;
using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    testData = sha256.ComputeHash("JoePesciWasGreatInGoodfellas");
}
CngKey cngKey         = CngKey.Import(cngBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
ECDsaCng eCDsaCng     = new ECDsaCng(cngKey);
byte[] signatureECDSA = eCDsaCng.SignHash(testData);
```

Note: As mentioned in the earlier post, please refer to the excellent information at [Microsoft CNG | How to import PEM encoded ECDSA private key into MS Key Storage Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080937/microsoft-cng-how-to-import-pem-encoded-ecdsa-private-key-into-ms-key-storage) to see to to create cngBlob from a private key in a PEM file.